# Is there a function to read ERC20 supply and give in output the number without decimals?

Tags: javascript, decimal, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

In my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54384890/render-javascript-number-as-solidity-erc20-decimals) I found out how to allow a user input a number of ERC20 tokens, and return the value with the number of decimals.

Say that the number of decimals for ERC20 is 4 and the user inputs 1.5 we will show them 1.5000 by using `.toFixed(4)`.

Now I am trying the reverse approach (more info after code) however it seems that there aren't any functions such as "fromFixed". For example, I read the total supply using web3js

```
checkBalance = async event => {
    try {
      const balance = await smartContract.methods.balanceOf(event).call();
      console.log(balance)
    } catch (err) {
      let error= 'Address Error';
      console.log(error)
    }
  };
```

Assuming that you have 10k ERC20, the code above will show in output 100000000 (which is 10,000.0000). I want to show the result with a dot for the last 4 decimals added so just 10000.0000 (10,000.0000).

I tried `balance.toFixed(4)`

however the output is even worse because I get 1000000000000 (10,000,0000.0000)`

I tried `console.log(web3.fromWei(balanceOf, 'ether'));` expecting that it will be converted to Ethereum's 18 decimals and the output will be something like 10 000.000000000000000000

This never works in the 'checkBalance' function as it always catches an error.

Comment: Your 'fromWei' doesn't work because the correct command is web3.utils.fromWei(x,y). However this is not the right approach because it won't return your expected output of 10000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that this has more to do on how to display numbers rather than with ethereum in general. In any case, if you want to display let's say 10000 as 10.000, so using four decimals, you can do `x=10000/1000;console.log(x.toFixed(4))`. More general, to display a number `n` using a different number of decimals `d` you can do: `x=n/(10^d);console.log(x.toFixed(d))`